# How can I interpret “talk somebody out of” in “He talked the mutawwa out of beheading or lashing me”?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I read the following sentence in Maureen Dowd’s article titled *[The Saudi Ambassador of Sangfroid](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/10/23/opinion/sunday/dowd-the-saudi-ambassador-of-sangfroid.html)* in today’s (October 22) New York Times:

> “When I was walking around a luxury mall in Riyadh with Jubeir, the robed, bearded religious police bore down on us, pointing at me and scolding in Arabic. They say they can see the outline of your body,” Jubeir translated. It took a surprisingly long time, given his stature as a top adviser to the future King Abdullah, but he *talked* the mutawwa *out of* beheading or lashing me."

It seemed to me that the usage of *out of* in the sentence “He talked the mutawwa out of beheading or lashing me” is very different from the *out of* in the sense of *from*, *without*, *apart* that I got used to.

Does *out of* here mean *not to (do)*? Or, should I take it as *talk someone out of (doing)* in the sense of *discuss with (persuade) someone thoroughly for him not to do*? Is "talk somebody out of" a very popular usage?

Answer (score 8):

To *[talk someone out of something](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/talk+out+of)* means to "persuade someone not to do something".  A related phrase is to *talk someone **into** doing something*, which means to persuade them to do it.

In this context, Jubeir is trying to persuade the mutawwa not to punish the writer for wearing what they considered indecent clothing.  Apparently the persuasion was difficult, for Ms. Dowd records that it "took a surprisingly long time".

And yes, *talk someone out of something* is a rather popular idiom, used in many contexts.

Comment: There's also the equally common [talk someone into](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=talk+him+out+of%2Ctalk+him+into&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), where in OP's context Jubeir could be trying to persuade the mutawwa to *spare* the writer, as opposed to *not punish* him.

Comment: And *talk him through sth* (explain sth), *talk him up/down* (emphasise his good/bad qualities), *talk him round* (to a position, usually of co-operation). Plus probably some others I can't think of.

Answer (score 0):

> *It seemed to me that the usage of out of ,,, is very different from the out of in the sense of from, without, apart that I got used to.*

In fact it is the same as "from" in its nuance of "away from": "He took the cup from/out of the cupboard/my hand."

You should focus on the verb "to talk + object + into/out of", which is more interesting:

OED:

> **to talk (a person) into or out of,** to persuade into, or dissuade from (something) by talking;
>
> Compare "to talk + object + preposition**: e.g. **to talk (a person)
> over or round**, to win over, or into compliance, by talking;
>
> **to talk (a person) through (something)**, to provide with a commentary on (some event); to take through with helpful explanation;

Answer (score -1):

"Talk"  is the method of communication

"out of" refers to the settled intention of the party talked to. They are persuaded out of their intention

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).